# Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: javascript, jquery, warnings

I am getting these warnings in my console and my script is not working fine

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix these warnings?

**My Scripts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Where you are loading this css put some code also

Comment: Have a firefox version 23 ?

Comment: My firefox Version is 25.0.1. This issue is also coming on Chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use this code to include your cdn files :
**Use https protocol in your url :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.10/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Or this pattern :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.10/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, this SO question (2nd answer) includes everything you need to know on urls.

Comment: So, if I have domain - which serve static files (.js, .css) with nonssl, is // still working?
In your post, I just see the domain code.jquery.com has a both http and https

Answer (score 17):

When a user visits a page served over `HTTP`, their connection is open for eavesdropping and `man-in-the-middle (MITM)` attacks. When a user visits a page served over `HTTPS`, their connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and `MITM` attacks.

However, if an `HTTPS` page includes `HTTP` content, the `HTTP` portion can be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served over `HTTPS`.  When an HTTPS page has `HTTP` content, we call that content `“mixed”`. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved `unencrypted` over `HTTP`.  The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain `HTTP` requests on `HTTPS` pages.

Got this from [Blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)

Answer (score 4):

This is a duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/) which contains a perfect and concise answer:

The page displayed with HTTPS is calling contents over HTTP.
This can be corrected by calling the page itself over HTTP or having the page to call its (probably dynamic) content with the same protocol as it was called itself.

Answer (score 3):

This kinds of issue will come up if you view the page as SSL. You need to modify your reference as https or else start the url as // so that you will avoid this issue.

Comment: Its very help full . Thank You!