# p:captcha throws - Blocked loading mixed active content on FireFox

Tags: jsf, firefox, primefaces, captcha

I am having problems trying to use the `<p:captcha>`. I am getting the following error in FireFox v34.0.5:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The check button is showing but not the captcha image

My applications is hosted in a secure (HTTPS) server but seems the captcha is connecting to a non secure server using HTTP

This is my web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value><xxxxx_recaptcha_generated_public_captcha_key></param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value><xxxxx_recaptcha_generated_private_captcha_key></param-value>
</context-param>
```

And my view file (forgottenOPassword.xhtml):

```
<p:captcha label="Captcha" rendered="#{passBB.showCaptcha}"/>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{passBB.verifyCaptcha}"
                 ajax="false" 
                 icon="ui-icon-check"
                 rendered="#{passBB.showCaptcha}"
                 value="Check"/>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the firefox version (v34.0.5)

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/18251128/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20605423/1391249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `secure` attribute of `<p:captcha>` to `true`. See also [VDL documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.0/core/primefaces-p/captcha.html): *"Enables https support"*.

```
<p:captcha ... secure="true" />
```

Or if you'd like to let it depend on the current request (e.g. when you've 2 versions of the webapp and the captcha is placed in some reusable tagfile/component), then check [`HttpServletRequest#isSecure()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure()) instead:

```
<p:captcha ... secure="#{request.secure}" />
```

Either way, if it evaluates to `true`, then the [`CaptchaRenderer` will use `https` instead of `http`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.0/org/primefaces/component/captcha/CaptchaRenderer.java/#59).

Comment: Thanks @BalusC your answer fix my problem. I will test it later and then I will give you the points