# Mixed Content error when using Nivo Lightbox over https

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, youtube, nivo-slider

I have a website which is accessed via **https** (and all resources are loaded via https too), where I have a [Nivo Lightbox](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-lightbox) which should show a Youtube video (as an overlay over the website). The JavaScript libraries I use (jquery and nivo-lightbox) are both stored on our server and referenced directly. Unfortunately, I get a Mixed Content error in the browser. It says that the YouTube-video (referenced with https) is from an insecured resource (so not https) and is therefore has been blocked.

I tried various things to overcome this problem, e.g. by [removing "https:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605423/blocked-loading-mixed-active-content) and just having "//youtube.com/..."; but couldn't solve the problem or other people who still couldn't solve the [issue](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/lightbox-issues-with-full-ssl-site)...

Does anyone have a similar problem and/or a solution? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered exactly the same issue. The solution that worked for me was editing the nivo-lightbox.min.js file. Look for string "http" and replace it with "https". The only downside for this solution is that it you will load videos in https even if the user requested to see your page on http protocol.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Had this same issue and this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your [nivo file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Codeinwp/Nivo-Lightbox-jQuery/master/dist/nivo-lightbox.min.js) to the latest version. I just did that and the mixed content error disappeared on my site.