# Make https request in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I am writing the following code,
$http.get(url).then....

is sending http request where as my server is configured for https. When using $http.get, I see following in the firebug console.

> Blocked loading mixed active content

What is the way to issue https requests in angularjs. No documentation could be found on this topic.

**EDIT**
My Exact code is:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                        return response;
                    });
```

The URL requested shown in firebug is :
GET http://localhost:8080/content/help/en/photoshop/product-details.js

Comment: `$http.get(url).then....` Could you add an example of your `url` param please ?

Comment: What URL are you requesting? What kind of response is it?

Comment: How did you include your scripts ??

Comment: @Maraboc, I used relative path like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/clientlibs/angularjs.js"></script>

Comment: is it the same thing for your css file??

Comment: remove http and start as //localhost:8080/content

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene pls add as answer. i want to choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

remove http and start as //localhost:8080/content

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605423/blocked-loading-mixed-active-content)