# Gh-Pages loading issue

Tags: github, github-pages

I am very very new at this so please bear with me. I am a PhD student in Psychology and I am running several online experiments. I took an existing developed github project, adapted it for my purposes and created a url using gh-pages. It worked and here is the url for reference: http://osmp.github.io/sm1/index.html

I needed to create another experiment, slightly altered, so did the same as I did before and used all the existing code as above, just changed the content of some of the text. However, now when I created the gh-page, it doesn't load, see here: https://osmp.github.io/rw3/index.html

As I said I am very new at this so maybe I am missing something very obvious, but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because of SSL protocol.

Github is forcing SSL on the new pages since mid June, as seen [here](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/).

As they replied in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931964/script-stops-working-when-hosted-on-github-pages) try to **swap the http js imports to https** (they seem to also serve them through ssl) and you should be golden.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the code as I have never coded before- so just go in and edit the content (i.e. the text), so it works on the first one and not the second... So I am guessing it must be github side. Any tips on how to stop this? Sorry as I said I am really new at this!

Comment: Github is forcing SSL on the new pages since mid June, as seen [here](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/)  you have two options,  use an older page that you had lying around or make it work through the SSL protocol.

Comment: @lundgirl Check my answer edit, that should solve your problem :)