# My GitHub page (css, js, style) doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, mixed-content

I'm entirely new to GitHub and I am facing some problems while trying to create my first project.

I am using GitHub (username.github.io) to preview (live). But locally my work is well but not in Github pages.

In Github pages, it doesn't work any CSS, js, or my style. All of my CSS, js, and style all in the index.html page. If I go to page source it shows all code but not work!
What I do for showing actual(like as localhost)?
The link is given below. Please see and tell me what I do?

https://mostafizur67.github.io

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocked loading mixed active content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605423/blocked-loading-mixed-active-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser console shows that your external resources are blocked:

```
(index):8 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mostafizur67.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mostafizur67.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):13 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mostafizur67.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Try loading the external resources using `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: @ msmolens Can i change http as https ?

Comment: @ msmolens can you tell me why some fonts , margin and page footer(size) change ? If you locally run this then show different from live !

Comment: @user3291513 Your browser could be using different zoom settings for the different domains. Try resetting the zoom (CTRL+0 or CMD+0 in Chrome/Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Actually not a Git question, it's really an HTML/CSS one.

You have links to `http` resources in an `https` page, and browsers do not like this. Prefer links like `//example.com/path/to/file` to `http://example.com/path/to/file` to let your browser pick the right protocol.

To debug this kind of issues, use the webmaster tools provided with your browser. For example, with Firefox, Right-click anywhere on page -> Inspect element. The console shows the errors.