# https: firefox blocks insecure content... but which content?

Tags: wordpress, firefox, https, block

I get the famous "Firefox has blocked content that isn't secure" on my site that I recently added SSL to.

I put an .htaccess redirect in place and the front page is fine, Firefox does not give me the warning. However, on pages with posts (this is a wordpress site) i get the above warning and I can't find the content that is causing it.

I went through the firebug net tab but couldn't find any http links. I opened up chrome and went through the network tab, I opened Fiddler and couldn't find the connection that is causing the problem there either.

How can I find the content that is blocked? Is there an option in Firefox that shows what is being blocked in a list?

Comment: In chrome right click on the page > Inspect Elements > Go to console tab. There you can find warnings, errors etc. Same in firefox.

Comment: Already did that. I need something more specific, none of the links or requests I see there seem to be the cause. Firefox just gives the message "Im blocking things" without indicating what it is blocking?

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing in error and warning queue? I'd like to check the site from my end, if you don't have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, right click on the page and go to Inspect Elements; that brings up the console and developer tools. Look at the "All Tab" to see a list of blocked elements.

Or use the add-on [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox; it has a much more extensive toolset.

A common issue are the links used for scripts from CDNs, like Google. You can use the URL construct `src="//url.to/script.js"` in your links and they will auto-detect http and https.

And see [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: I already used firebug (see question) but could not find the content. There are many links in the Net tab and none of them are http instead of https. But then again, Firefox does say it's blocking certain content? Sae for Chrome.

Comment: Search within the source code for plain http links. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire

Comment: In your link I found the answer: I shouldn't look at the "net" tab in firebug but in the console -> all tab. It has a neat list of blocked content which allowed me to pinpoint exactly what was blocked. In my case a twitter plugin.