# Dynamic webpage content not appearing if https is used in url

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have deployed a new SSL certificate for our website.
We have noticed that dynamic webpages are not loading (data from mysql db) if 'https' is prefixed, at the same time if we open webpage without https the page is loading properly (data from mysql db is getting pulled and displayed).

```
With 'https'

https://somedomain.com/display.php?pageid=9


Without 'https' (plain http)

http://somedomain/display.php?pageid=9
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the jquery library can't be loaded because it uses http and not https so none of your client-side code is working.

From firebug :

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"
```

You should load jquery with https as such :

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3
```

Or like this :

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3
```

and depending with what protocol the page it accessed it will load the library over http or https.

In general once you switch to https you should load all your scripts over https otherwise they will be blocked as considered a security flaw.

You can learn more here : [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: Expanding on @NeilMasters statement: use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` instead because the web browser will default it to the protocol used upon accessing your webpage