# Call http:// url from https:// Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ip, mixed-content

I want to get IP of computer in my site. For that I used http://ipinfo.io from ajax.Get Method. It works fine on `http://` Page but on `https://` page it gives the following error

> Blocked loading mixed active content http://ipinfo.io/

So how to get IP in JavaScript on `https://` page?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/3176651) explains things

Comment: But https://ipinfo.in gives 401 Error.So,i have to use http://ipinfo.io in my Page.

Comment: ipinfo.in gives a 401 error for HTTPS access if you're not paying them. It says that you need to pay to access via HTTPS. see [pricing](http://ipinfo.io/pricing)

Comment: Sorry, none that I know of. :(

Comment: Ok.....
Any other way to get IP in JavaScript

Comment: It's better to do that with server-side languages like PHP or Java... Why JavaScript ?

Comment: @SiZiOUS,Ya than i do it by Server Side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not Possible.

Achieve by Server Side Code by User Control.