# NopCommerce with SSL - blocked content that isnt secure

Tags: http, ssl, https, web-hosting, nopcommerce

I have NopCommerce 3.40 and I have SSL set up on my web-host.  This is the message that I'm getting when I run it in Firefox. (This is not a localhost test).  I only get the blocked content message on the Front side of NopCommerce.  Everything on the Admin side looks fine and secure.

Some help getting rid of this Blocked content message would be appreciated.  Please don't show me how to disable the message in the browser.

[image]

**EDIT: ADDED** So I think this is the error (in pic below).  Unfortunately in nopCommerce I havent been able to locate the call to Google API's.  I have a feeling this call is localized from a database string.  So I could use some help with which table or how to edit it on the Admin side. 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire). In the absence of useful information (like information from Firebug or the script that's causing it on your site), that's about all we can offer you.

Comment: This is not an API, this is call to Google Font. Most probably used by your custom theme. :)