# mathjax is not rendered when my page is on Dropbox

Tags: mathjax

I have some *`mathjax` enhanced* WWW pages on Dropbox (e.g., [mathjax_test.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57755729/mathjax_test.html)), that are rendered like this

[image]

while on localhost they are rendered like this

[image]

The code of the page is

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
  <head>
    <title>Test of mathjax</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=latin-1"></>
  </head>
  <body>
      We analyze the common case in which the dynamic load can
      be expressed by a constant load vector \(\boldsymbol r\)
      modulated by an adimensional function of time,
      \(f(t)\) (e.g., the seismic excitation can be
      described in such terms).
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there something that can be done to have `mathjax` code rendered correctly when the page is fetched from Dropbox?

Comment: Try changing http to https for src pointing to MathJax.js. since Dropbox enforces https the http call will be blocked for security reasons.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I would say that it's my browser that sources the javascript from cdn.mathjax.org,,, I would say so but it works! If you care to put your comment in an answer I'd be glad to upvote and accept your answer but thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Glad to hear it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Dropbox only serves content over `https` but in your source MathJax.js is loaded via `src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/...`.

Browsers block such `http` calls (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)), hence MathJax is not loaded and accordingly can't render the page.

(You can open the JavaScript console in the developer tools of your browser to see an error message about this.)