# Mixed Content Issue $http.get AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, mixed-content

I have an application running on HTTPS protocol. I wrote an Angular function to get the data using $http service.

```
factory.loadImages = function(callback){

        $http.get("http://gainsight.0x10.info/api/image?page_no=0")
             .success(function(data){

                callback(data);

            }).error(function(status,error){

                console.log(status);

            });
    };
```

I am getting the below Mixed Content errors:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.hackerearth.com/gainsight-ui-development-hiring-challenge-1/problems/30146b3bf6954bba9752bd5599b3c8aa/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://gainsight.0x10.info/api/image?page_no=0'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Now i tried to change the http://gainsight.0x10.info/api/image?page_no=0 to https://gainsight.0x10.info/api/image?page_no=0 in my `$http.get` service which is unfortunately not available.

Any Help.. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the protocol!!

Instead of using `https://...` just use `//...`.

Hope it works :)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/2748080)

Comment: it just prepends "https" to your url (or http, regarding of yout current protocol)

Answer (score -1):

Even if you are able to call an http endpoint you will not be able to load the ressource because it is on a different domain and you have a cross domain issue (unless you fix that with jsonp or cors )

http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/