# Blocked loading mixed active content in web page

Tags: css, html

I'm using web page template which uses

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900); to apply text font in all pages.
```

I tried to download the code and use into my web pages. In Firefox and Chrome the code is working but in IE it's not working.

I tried to use only the link but I get error:`Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900"` because I use SSL.

Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: Have you tried changing the link to `https://`?

Comment: @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900); to apply text font in all pages.

Comment: Can you propose some elegant solution?