# BigCommerce API - PHP AJAX on Cart for Weight Returns

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, curl, bigcommerce

I'm trying to return product weights so they display on the cart for my customers.

In the cart template, I'm calling this external JS file from the cart template in BigCommerce

storefront: `https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/cart.php` or backend template: `cart.html`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var url = 'http://xxxx.com/cartProduct.php';
var prodWeights;    


 $(".prod_SKU").each(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {sku: $(this).text()},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,

        success: function (result) {
             prodWeights = result;
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });    
});



 console.log(prodWeights);


 });
```

So it passes the SKU properly to the PHP file, "cartProduct.php":

```
<?php

 $sku = $_POST['sku'];

 $api_url = 'https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products?sku=' . sku;
 $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); 
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0') );                                   
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx" ); 
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );   
 $response = curl_exec( $ch );   
 $result = json_decode($response); 
 print_r($result);


 ?>
```

I believe there might be an authorization issue, when I try to hit my PHP as just "http://", I get this error:
[image: error1]

When I try "https://" I get this:
[image: error 2]

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL installed on your script? Try accessing the URL directly via the browser over HTTPS and see if it loads, and if it asks you to manually accept the SSL.

Comment: Also, performing synchronous Ajax requests within a loop is very inefficient, and will most likely lock the browser. You should try re-structuring this to be asynchronous. One such way would be to use a counter that you increment in your success callback, so that once the counter = # of skus, you know that all the requests have finished, and you can now safely move to the final callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `cartProduct.php` and the `cart template` making the XMLHttpRequest reside on the same domain.
e.g.

```
xxx.com/cart.php ->
XmlHttpRequest to xxx.com/cartProduct.php ->
cURL SSL-Request to store-xxx.com ->
output to browser
```

Otherwise see [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and configure a `JSONP` request insead.

Ensure you set the Content-Type of the response header when jQuery uses `dataType: "json"`. JQuery applies an accept `application/json, text/javascript`  request header when it is used.

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason.

You should be sending the encoded value, and not the decoded variable output from `print_r` as it applies PHP specific formatting to the output.

Example:

```
$json = '{"a": "b"}';
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

Will output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [a] => b
)
```

Which is not valid JSON syntax.

So in cartProduct.php

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 $sku = $_POST['sku'];

 $api_url = 'https://store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products?sku=' . sku;
 $ch = curl_init();
 //...
 ob_end_clean();
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $response = curl_exec($ch); 
 echo $response;
 exit;
```

Be sure to remove the ending php script tag, as any line endings or include files afterward will render an additional line break in the output, and cause extra data to be submitted.

Your `console.log(prodWeights);` Needs to be inside your `success` function calls, as the variable will not become available to the javascript until after the ajax call is made.

eg `ajaxRequest -> console.log(prodWeights) -> success -> declare prodWeights`

So the script would need to be changed to

```
 success: function (result) {
    var prodWeights = result;
    console.log(prodWeights);
 },
```

Your url can be easier translated for the client's current protocol by using a relative URI `var url = '/cartProduct.php';` Otherwise if you are not wanting to support both protocols, be sure to redirect the user to the correct protocol if you're not already.

---

Last but not least, you should invest some researching into jQuery [.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [.deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) methods instead of using `async: false`. non-asynchronous requests are depreciated and will eventually be removed from browsers (like Java and npapi), which your developer window warns you about at the top of the console output. See: [XMLHttpRequest Spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4r2avewo/ (asynchronous ajax chain, with realtime ticker, view XHR status in console to validate requests are being chanined)

```
var def = $.Deferred();
var promise = def.promise()
$('.prod_SKU').each(function() {
  var sku = $(this).text();
  //this creates the chaining
  promise = promise.then(function() {
    return $.ajax('/path/to/resource.php', {
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {'sku': sku},
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
promise.done(function(){
    //do something after the last request has completed
});
def.resolve(); //start the ajax request chain
```

Comment: In this case, `cartProduct.php` is an externally hosted file, as BigCommerce is a closed source platform that does not support custom server side code. Additionally though, using `jsonp` is not explicitly required, as simply setting the CORS header on the external script would suffice. Good catch on the invalid php response.

Comment: Correct, among other methods, which should be explained in the linked Same-Origin Policy reference. Though I have found most users grasp JSONP easier, since it is just working out a simple call_back function name within the Javascripts, as opposed to modifying the cross-origin request headers, and less chance of the developer using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` eg: `echo call_back_name(' . $result . ');';`

Comment: Thank you, my issue was resolved with the CORS and PHP headers. However, I notice that Mix-Media issue because my PHP is hosted on a non-SSL certified server (and will never be SSL-certified, this is a private development server), the workaround for that was browser-inclusive [see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire], is there any way to make this work naturally without telling the browser?

Comment: You can use `stunnel` to facilitate the SSL requirement in your development environment. https://www.stunnel.org/index.html You may need to trust and install the generated certificate to remove the invalid certifcate warnings.

Comment: @AndreaRose each individual browser/client would need to manually accept the certificate in order for the JS request to work, which obviously is not ideal. There is no way to bypass this via JS. If this application is meant to work for publicly for all users, you would absolutely need to purchase an SSL if you wish to use this over HTTPS.

Comment: @love @fyrye So would `stunnel` not work for my desired application. Essentially our company has no place to host this code, as you know BigC has no PHP hosting-- so we're placing our  applications/scripts on a webserver whose sole purpose is for code hosting / image hosting / holds a test wordpress blog / test opencart stores etc. We can't get this SSL certified because we only need it for a few things-- and I know SSL certs are a little expensive. Stunnel wouldn't facilitate my needs?

Comment: `stunnel` is only applicable for your development environments so that you do not need to set up SSL hosting during development. Your production/deployment web server, serving the AJAX request clients from BigC should be able to implement SSL and should if you're dealing with commerce data online anyway.

Comment: @fyrye Definitely, and I've been trying to reach for something like this for our company anyway. I believed this to be the ultimate issue it comes down to anyway-- however, I appreciate your understanding and to-the-point responses. Out of curiosity do you know if there are any SSL-server hosting services? I don't want to pay for a huge server if we can just get a little chunk of hosting. Sounds stupid-- I know we should ultimately just purchase the cert. for our deployment server but just searching for alternatives.

Comment: Dreamhost Secure Hosting is the cheapest I have found for Unlimited Storage/Traffic PHP+MySQL+SSL. I believe it is $10/mo for PHP shared hosting and $20/yr for SSL certificate from Comodo. To top it off only host I've found that guarantees 100% uptime. https://www.dreamhost.com/hosting/shared/ Looks like SSL is free now..

Comment: @AndreaRose could you please update your question with the page location the ajax script is being executed on. eg: `https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/products.php`

Comment: @fyrye Much appreciated, I will look into hosting with them. I've also updated my question as well.