# Openlayers 3: Getting data from multiple features

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I took the example from the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/icon.html) and added another feature. On clicking the feature data will be displayed in a popup.
I add another feature with different data. If I click the features in series it'll show the data from the first feature I clicked. If I click a feature, click somewhere else and then the other feature: It works like expected.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzojm1va/) showing this problem. (In my firefox the map will only show if I click on the 'shield' icon in the top-left corner of the address bar and select 'Disable Protection on This Page'. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire))

Seems like the correct feature is not taken using this example code:

```
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
      });
  if (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coord);
    $(element).popover({
      'placement': 'top',
      'html': true,
      'content': feature.get('name')
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  } else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
  }
});
```

My goal is to click on the features directly one by one and get the correct data displayed.

**EDIT:**
Seems like it's not a problem of OpenLayers but of the popover. When I insert:

```
console.log(feature.get('name'));
```

It'll come up with the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add two points next to each other. So close to each other so you can not disnguish them visually.
Change your features declaration to this:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500
});

var iconFeature2 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([100000, 100000]),//here is the change
  name: 'Null Null Island',
  population: 200,
  rainfall: 100
});
```

Also note that the default projection of your map is EPSG:3857. The coordinates you are trying to pass seems to be on 4326.

You also declare `iconStyle` twice which doesnt make any difference, just for the sake of correctness

**UPDATE**

Your main problem comes from bootsrap `popover`. To overcome the issue you need to do a bit of dirty job and update the content on each click dinamically. Use this piece of code to achive it

```
  $(element).data("bs.popover").options.content= feature.get('name');
  $(element).popover("show");
```

and a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/aft4qcup/)

Comment: The jsfiddle was not saved correctly. I've updated the link a few minutes ago when I realized the problem.

Comment: Ok now it is more clear. remove the `s` from your https to get the mapbox tiles. http://jsfiddle.net/zzojm1va/ . I am checking your problem. If I come up with something I ll let you know

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer to deal with your main problem.

Comment: I came up with the root of the problem at the very same time :D But thx for the solution. I didn't know how to update the popover correctly. This helped a lot!