# CDN not being accessed from username.github.io?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, github-pages

I'm trying to host a github page [consisting of this featured html file](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h).

The dropdown menu included will indeed dropdown upon browsing my offline version alright, but fails to do so once uploaded and viewed on 
username.github.io

The online page seems to work correctly except for this feature.

Any reason it should behave this way, or fixes ?

Best,

**Edit :**
Actually the issue seems to be with the CDN's that I was trying to include, because even the Bootstrap css stylesheet won't load ?

Here we go : https://marsupilam.github.io/

Comment: Can we have a link to your github site so we can see the code on there?

Comment: Check your console for errors and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main page is served over **https**, your browser mixed content security then disallow loading of resources served over **http**.

Just change your CDN urls to use **https** and not **http**.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. See also [this very clear answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: So, maybe, you can approve my answer.