# Why Blocked loading mixed active content?

Tags: jquery, https, mozilla

Today I spotted the error

`Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=jQuery2240797948164524662_1471014635124&_=1471014635125"`

in firefox.

Here is my code

```
function getCurrentWeather(){
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
      var lat=data["lat"];
      var lon=data["lon"];
      updateWeatherDisplay(lat,lon);         
      updateAddress(data["city"],", "+data["region"]);
    });
}
```

But here is the other code, that makes equivalent query to the api - with no errors!:

```
function getLocation() {
    $.get('http://ip-api.com/json', function(loc) {
        $('#location').text(loc.city + ', ' + loc.region + ', ' + loc.country);
        getWeather(loc.lat, loc.lon, loc.countryCode);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        getWeather();
    });
}
```

Both examples runs on https://codepen io.

I already know that I should use https:// to call to api.
But I am curious, why no errors in the second example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: [Because it's a security flaw to load content from an untrusted third party](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: I put the links here not in the question. My buggy example - https://codepen.io/pbweb/pen/GqGYag?editors=1010. And the working one- http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/OXBwxL

Comment: @Liam Thank you for the links and provided info but why the second example runs with no blocking issues - it also uses http to refer to api!

Comment: Oh god! - I spotted that the issue appears only sometimes! It's totaly unreliable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because https://codepen/ is use **secure** (**https** protocol) and http://ip-api.com use **Insecure** (http protocol).

ip-api.com currently does **not support** https, if they support https you may use **secure** (**https** protocol) https://ip-api.com

```
function getCurrentWeather(){
  $.getJSON("https://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
   var lat=data["lat"];
   var lon=data["lon"];
   updateWeatherDisplay(lat,lon);         
   updateAddress(data["city"],", "+data["region"]);
  });
}
```