# Mixed protocol (http / https) request using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I need to call a WebService from a distant server with `ajax` in order to send some informations stored in the `sessionStorage` of the navigator, this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://10.7.138.42:6061/CatchEvent.asmx/CollectData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "pDataDictionnary": lDataCollected }),
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
            alert('success');
        }
    },
    error: function (exception) {
        alert('Exeption : ' + exception);
    }
});
```

The pool that I'm using is under `https` and when I change the calling request to `https` it doesn't work. I need somtehing to ignore the calling method because I can't change it for the reason that the application is on a distant server that I cannot configure.

Comment: your distant server is configured with https and your local app is in http. Is that what your concern or in reverse?

Comment: @Keppy the reverse my local app is under https and the distant under http how to ignor this?

Comment: You can not just “ignore” this. If this needs to run in just your own local browser, then you can perhaps get it to suppress it using some startup flags/options - but you can not work around security measures like that for pages intended to be used by the public. Either get the remote site to support HTTPS, or downgrade your side of it to HTTP.

Comment: @anass90 [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire/18251129#18251129) and try the solution they have mentioned in comments. :-)