# Why wont this script work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm having this script, and it works fine in every browser except firefox.

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName('toTop-transparent')[0];
window.onscroll = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 7) {
        header.className = 'header-colored';
        arrow.className = 'toTop';
    } else {
        header.className = 'header-transparent';
        arrow.className = 'toTop-transparent';
    }
};
```

The script doesn't seem to load at all. It's supposed to change the color of my header on scroll, and bring forth a 'back to top' button, but in firefox it does nothing. Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

I've tried updating browser to latest version, start in safe-mode without any add-ons.

Edit: I no longer have any errors in console on my site. The script still won't load, it seems like there is something in the script that firefox doesn't understand?

Comment: You should change the "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" to "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" that is http to https when you use it in your code

Comment: possible dublicate for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire

Comment: @GraveyardQueen I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble seeing whats the difference between those two? I tried removing the http:// from the <script>, but it didn't help. Was that what you meant?

Comment: nope instead of http://... use https://.. and please check the explanation as provided by @Vladimir M

Comment: @GraveyardQueen Ah, yes, that fixed the error in console. Other script still doesn't work though. I am readin the question he linked now, but it basically just tells me what you did. I'm stilling not getting the other script to work.

Comment: Can you post the html code as well so that we can try it out as well?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen https://jsfiddle.net/0owz7kt5/1/ , url for site if its easier: https://ludviklund.github.io/finalassignment2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works in IE, Chrome and FF:

```
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName('toTop-transparent')[0];
var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  var y = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

  if (y > 7) {
    console.log('here 1')
    header.className = 'header-colored';
    arrow.className = 'toTop';
  } else {
    console.log('here 2')
    header.className = 'header-transparent';
    arrow.className = 'toTop-transparent';
  }
};
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zevane/zf8d4u36/

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY