# Why do I get "blocked:mixed-content"?

Tags: jquery, http

I use a free website from 000webhost, I had it registered since few years and now they forced me to migrate to their new user area which I did, but now my website is broken, I had a loading thingy while the page loads, a gif image is displayed until the page has fully loaded but it doesn't work anymore, I checked the F12 Network tab and I see that jquery.min.js and modernizr.js got the following status: "blocked:mixed-content" - size 0 B - Time 0 ms.

How can I fix this guys? It worked perfectly on the previous host.

Comment: a simple google with that error `blocked:mixed-content` will give you a solution. search and research

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the migration involve going from HTTP to HTTPS? If that's the case, you need to load everything else on the page over HTTPS too.

Preferably, you shouldn't include the protocol at all when you specify URLs for assets, that way they will load over the same protocol as the page itself. 
So, instead of `src="http://cdn.example.com...` you should put `src="//cdn.example.com...`