# Mixed Active Content blocked from bootstrap font on localhost

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, yii2, mixed-content

I'm using the Framework Yii2 which include Bootstrap. I have this error about mixed active content:

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://localhost/my-web-site/web/assets/b9b53b8/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2”

I checked and this is a font provided by Bootsrap. I don't use it directly on my written code. But what seems strange to me is that I'm on localhost (using xampp) but `mixed active content` errors can only happen when using `https`protocole, am I right?

How should I remove this error? Why is it happening?

---

**EDIT**

I think this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18251128/3520621) because:

1. It happen on localhost (which is over http and not https)
2. The font causing the error is not on a cdn but on a local path (“http://localhost/my-web-site/web/assets/b9b53b8/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2”).

Maybe I'm wrong when I say this is not a duplicate but then, could you point me out what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it does not seems to be a duplicate for me because (1) it happen on localhost (which is over http and not https) and (2) the font causing the error is not on a cdn but on a local path (“http://localhost/my-web-site/web/assets/b9b53b8/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2”). I read the "possible duplicate" link and I don't think this is the same kind of issue, but maybe I'm wrong and thus could you point me out what am I missing? Thank's.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Are you getting the same result using multiple browsers?

Comment: What is the URL that is loading the link to the glyp icons?