# TYPO3 - Blocked loadin mixed active content in console

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

On my live site 'mysite.com' I see the following error message in the console:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “dev.mysite.com/fileadmin/templates/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2”
[Learn More]
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:24860
Blocked loading mixed active content “dev.mysite.com/fileadmin/templates/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0”
[Learn More]
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:24860
```

I have no clue how it got there and don't remember what I changed. Where do I need to look for and how can I fix this?

I do have a Development Site ... dev.mysite.com ... and for deployment I just move the new files into the live folder.

Edit: I want to fix this problem by loading the files from my live site ... but I don't know from where I'm loading those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: But why are they loading from my dev site at all? ... I want to load them from my live site ... but I don't know how they got there. How can I find out from where I load those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those font-files are probably loaded from CSS I assume you already load your CSS from the dev server.
Check this out in the your browser (Network-tab).
You might see it in the HTML source. But the loading also could be initiated by javascript. so you need to check that too for any references to your dev-server.

Then you need to identify the source of this inclusion. If it's in the javascript it's obvious.
The CSS includes can be initiated in multiple places. The most common are in typoscript, so first try: go to the Template Analyzer and look for your dev-server domain. Identify the template and modify it.