# Django AWS Zappa deployement satic files error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zappa

I've manage to deploy my site to AWS Lambda using Zappa which was complicated but i got there in the end. However i'm running into an issue where some of my icons are not loading. Please see the consol log below.

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:8000/static/scss/icons/simple-line-icons//fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf?-i3a2kk"[Learn More]
login
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:8000/static/scss/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.woff"[Learn More]
login
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:8000/static/scss/icons/material-design-iconic-font//fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=1.8.36"[Learn More]
login
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:8000/static/scss/icons/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2"[Learn More]
login
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost:8000/static/scss/icons/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2"[Learn More]
```

The site is hosted at https://h28ijhkwy3.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Demo/account/login

So, i believe this files are being called from my style.css file using:

```
@import url(../scss/icons/material-design-iconic-font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css);
```

I have tried putting the full AWS S3 path instead but it still doesn't work and i still get the same errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firefox?
If so, this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/1014508

TLDR; Mixed Active Content is blocked by default in Firefox 23

Comment: Yeah i did see that too, which i get is a security feature and that's fine. my question is why is it trying to go to localhost:8000? i've looked all through the settings.py and local_settings.py but it's still looking for localhost for the icons. It's very odd.

Comment: Could you please post your zappa settings and your settings.py files?