# Deployed Node application not running static JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-app-engine, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Node web app that lets the user play an interactive fiction game made with Dedalus. https://github.com/pistacchio/Dedalus

The application runs fine locally, but when deployed the game does not run in the browser.

I have tried deploying to Google Cloud's App Engine and Firebase, and I have also tried deploying on Heroku. In both cases the game doesn't run in the browser and will only display my game's background image.

These are the assets included in the game's HTML page. 
The game's JavaScript file's depend on Jquery and the doT.js template engine.

```
<script src="http://olado.github.io/doT/doT.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./dedalus.js"></script>
<script src="./dedalus-web.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/plain/story.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

I would like to be able to run this game in the browser as I am able to locally. I have scoured this site and the web for answers to my problem, but have not found an answer.

I would really appreciate any advice as to what I need to do to get my game to run on the web.

My source code is on GitHub https://github.com/mttwh/thegame

Comment: What happens in the browser inspector?

Comment: There is an error in the console that says "Blocked loading of mixed active content" for the doT.js file and the jquery file. Looks like it may have to do with the http protocol in the link not matching my site. Am looking into the solution described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire