# CORS Configuration Issue in Blazor .NET 8 Application

Tags: asp.net-core, https, cors, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor application using .NET 8 and I've encountered an issue with CORS when trying to send requests from my Blazor WebAssembly client to a backend API. Despite setting up CORS in `Program.cs` as shown below, I'm still receiving CORS errors in the browser. The application is using HTTPS, but the API currently uses HTTP, and I suspect this might be causing the "Blocked loading mixed active content" error.

Here's how I've configured CORS in `Program.cs`:

```
  builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
           policy =>`
            {
               policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

   var app = builder.Build();
   app.UseCors();
   // Other configurations follow...
```

When I attempt to send a request to the API, I receive the following error in the browser's console:

`Blocked loading mixed active content “http://[api-url]”`

I understand that this error is due to the browser blocking insecure requests from a secure origin. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Is there a way to allow these requests in development mode, or do I need to move my API to HTTPS?

I would appreciate any advice on how to correctly configure CORS in this scenario or how to handle mixed content issues in Blazor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I suddenly getting a "Blocked loading mixed active content" issue in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire)

Comment: please use HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

> or do I need to move my API to HTTPS

Best option:
Yes. You should move your API to HTTPS. You did not state if your API is running in development mode or production. Either way it is easy enough to set up https for it which will fix your issue. And if in production, it should be done anyways. ([Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is free.)

Other option:
The other option is run your Blazor application in http mode and it won't give you the mixed mode error, but creates additional limitations as to what you can test in your Blazor application which may or may not hinder development. [Features restricted to secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts/features_restricted_to_secure_contexts)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a Content Security Policy for your API.
This is not a recommended approach, because mixing HTTP and HTTPS has been discouraged by all modern browser.

This is an example of CSP typically used for images :
`Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:; img-src http: https:;`
This CSP allow image from **http** and **https** source and all other request *only* from **https**.

The CSP you need has to be applied on the WebAssembly side.
You need to add the following code to your **index.html**:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
     content="default-src 'self'; 
              connect-src 'self' http://[API-DOMAIN];">
```